# Get JsonKey name back from enum

Tags: flutter, enums

I have a simple enum in Flutter, say

```
enum Bear {
    panda,
    @JsonValue("black_bear") blackBear,
    @JsonValue("brown_bear") brownBear,
}
```

How do I retrieve `black_bear` from `Bear.blackBear`?

Comment: how about using enhaced enum?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am using enhanced enums, I was trying to avoid having a jsonValue in the enum again (repeating the value of the JsonValue), if possible

Comment: if you consider `_` you can use `.name` extension. like `Bear.blackBear.name` will return `blackBear`

Comment: I need it to return black_bear.

Comment: I see what you mean, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enhanced enum,

```dart
enum Animal {
  panda('panda'),
  blackBear("black_bear"),
  brownBear("brown_bear");

  const Animal(this.key);
  final String key;
}
```

And you can use `Animal.blackBear.key;` to get `black_bear` .

Comment: I wanted to avoid repeating, like so: @JsonValue("brown_bear") brownBear("brown_bear"). If the param is named key do I not need to repeat? Is key a special parameter?

Comment: *Is key a special parameter?* no, I just named it, you can include as many as you like